# Searching Exact Match From Comma-Separated Values

Tags: search, filter, match, lookup

I really hope someone can help, I have a google form where a multiple option of times can be selected, when in google sheets this appears as comma separated. I want to separate the data into columns matching exactly what the time is selected, returning what is in column `A` and Filtering by what they can do, this will need to be an `ARRAYFORMULAR` so any new entries automatically get sorted

`A` = Name Of Memeber

`B` = Comma Seperated Data

`C` = Roll or Talent

`D:O` = Different times ranging from 12PM to 11AM

If I use split function and someone has select times 5PM onwards then then 5PM column D where this should be 12PM, using Match dont seems to tell me I can only reference a single column or single row.

This is what I have right now and for the most part it works unless the CSV Data has someone who has stated they are available at 12 PM then it will show them in both columns 12PM and 2PM where they need only appear in 12PM

I want the result to be Column A if the data contains a matching time and the person is a singer or entertainer in column D

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A, SEARCH(TEXT($D$1, "H AM/PM"),$B$2:$B), ($C$2:$C = "SINGER") + ($C$2:$C = "Entertainer")),""))
```

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zJXSLkoTwKw_fyOsRGz92P-p-5wrXAQWZ5PvWgcg9FM/edit?usp=sharing)

[IMAGE OF RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDJ3u.png)

This returns mostly what I want but search is not an exact match Test 5 has 12PM not 2PM and yet shows in 2PM also.

Comment: It could be helpfull to get a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Hi Mike, Im not great with this stuff, but here is an example sheet you can view - [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zJXSLkoTwKw_fyOsRGz92P-p-5wrXAQWZ5PvWgcg9FM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E2, drag to the right

```
=iferror(query(arrayformula(trim(split(flatten($A$2:$A&"~"&split($B$2:$B,",")&"~"&$C$2:$C),"~"))),"select Col1 where Col2='"&to_text(value(E$1))&"' and Col3='Example 2' ",0))
```

[image]

Comment: You SIR are great thank you so much for your help, off cause you base answer still only gave one result but adding in the OR query in gave me the desired result

```=iferror(query(arrayformula(trim(split(flatten($A$2:$A&"~"&split($B$2:$B,",")&"~"&$C$2:$C),"~"))),"select Col1 where Col2='"&to_text(value(F$1))&"' and (Col3='Example 2' or Col3='Example 1') ",0))```